# Query Function not picking date range

Tags: google-sheets

On sheet 1 I have written 2 queries firs cell B5(datasource sheet2) & other on D5(datasource sheet3) as we can see that that the first query was able to pick the date range but the 2nd query is not showing dates

I checked the date format on both table and date range filter & they are same, can anyone please tell what am I doing wrong here is link of the spread sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZV3-cOI1iCjR6gQ3P16a0he_0UKyf-NTYmtJWFiPXh4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `date` parameter:

```
=QUERY(Sheet3!A:F,"Select B,
sum(D),
sum(E) 
where B>= date'"&text(F1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
and B<= date'"&text(F2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'      
group by B")
```